# Adding a Portal Category within SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, portal

I'm wanting to add a new 'Portal Category' within a SharePoint List.

[image]

How would I be able to do that?

Comment: Please delete thread. I've found the answer within: https://tenant/_layouts/15/termstoremanager.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can Create a **Managed Metadata column** for portal category then you can add it to your list from **list settings** check this reference of [microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-managed-metadata-column-8fad9e35-a618-4400-b3c7-46f02785d27f)